# How can I tokenize the username using JWT on Google App Engine(Python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, jwt

I'm trying to have my backend server sign and send the username at the end of an OAuth request. The example I'm trying to follow uses this package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt) but my backend is in Google App Engine. So, I was wondering how I can achieve the same (signing the username with some secret) inside the App Engine/webapp2 framework?

Comment: Could you go into more concrete detail about what you mean by "have my backend server sign and send the username at the end of an OAuth request"?

Comment: And I assume since you're using node on GAE that you're dealing with custom runtimes or managedVMs?

Answer (score 1):

First download [python jwt](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt) to folder `lib` of projects

Code:

```
import cgi
import datetime
import webapp2
from base_handler import BaseRequestHandler, login_required
from webapp2 import Route
from models import Customer
from lib import jwt
import logging

def login_required(fn):
    def check(self, *args, **kargs):
        auth = self.request.headers.get('Authorization')
        login_info = jwt.decode(auth, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
        # your verify login token here
        logging.error(login_info)
        # verify success
        fn(self, *args, **kargs)
    return check


class LoginHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
    def login(self):
        username = self.request.get('username')
        password = self.request.get('password')
        if Customer.login(username, password) is True:
            encoded = jwt.encode({'username': username}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
            self.response.write({'token': encoded})
            return

        self.response.write('login unsuccess', status=404)


class APIHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
    @login_required
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('product found')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    Route('/login', handler=LoginHandler, handler_method='login', name='login', methods=['POST']),
      ('/', APIHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Note: for test client you can usage [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=vi) and add header (token are get from login request)